# Speed up triple-nested For Loop in R with vectorization

Tags: r, for-loop, vectorization, apply

**Overview:** The following is an important chunk of R code for my basketball stats website. At a high level, the R code converts lineup statistics, where each row represents a unique lineup (a lineup is a combo of 5-players playing together), into on/off statistics, where each row represents a team's overall statistics with a specific player either (a) on-the-court, or (b) off-the-court.

I felt that a small snippet of data would not work for this reproducible example, and so I've uploaded the data to a Google Sheet, and made the sheet public. The reproducible code grabs this CSV data, but you can just as easily download the file by visiting the url.

With all of this said, here is the triple-nested for loop I am working with, which I've done my best to comment clearly:

```
# Raw Data Is Lineup Data - Each Row contains stats for a single lineup (combination of 5 basketball players)
sheets_url <- 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1GjDbWfZglwdwMwhNemWpX6uWjhmYfpQe-WNcCNE8EK4/export?format=csv&id=1GjDbWfZglwdwMwhNemWpX6uWjhmYfpQe-WNcCNE8EK4&gid=218640693'
raw.lineup.stats <- httr::content(httr::GET(url = sheets_url))

# Will contain the final output
on.off.stats <- c()

all_seasons <- c('1718', '1819')
# Loop each season
for(i in 1:length(all_seasons)) {
  # Filter Lineup Data to include only lineups / stats from this season
  this_season <- all_seasons[i]
  season.lineup.stats <- raw.lineup.stats %>% dplyr::filter(season == this_season)
  all_teams <- unique(season.lineup.stats$teamId)

  # Loop each team that appeared in data for this season
  for(j in 1:length(all_teams)) { 
    # Filter Lineup Data again to include only lineups / stats for this team
    print(paste0(j, ': ', all_teams[j]))
    this_team <- all_teams[j]
    team.season.lineup.stats <- season.lineup.stats %>% dplyr::filter(teamId == this_team)
    players_on_team <- unique(c(team.season.lineup.stats$onCtId1, team.season.lineup.stats$onCtId2, team.season.lineup.stats$onCtId3, team.season.lineup.stats$onCtId4, team.season.lineup.stats$onCtId5))

    # Loop each player on team j
    for(k in 1:length(players_on_team)) {
      # Identify if player is on-court or off-court - is his ID one of the 5
      this_player <- players_on_team[k]
      this.players.teams.lineup.stats <- team.season.lineup.stats %>%
        dplyr::mutate(isOnOrOff = ifelse(onCtId1 == this_player | onCtId2 == this_player | onCtId3 == this_player 
                                         | onCtId4 == this_player | onCtId5 == this_player, 'On Ct', 'Off Ct')) %>%
        dplyr::mutate(playerId = this_player) %>%
        dplyr::select(playerId, isOnOrOff, everything())

      # Convert this team' lineup data into 2 Rows: 1 for team's stats w/ player on-court, and 1 for team's stats w/ player off-court
      this.players.onoff.stats <- this.players.teams.lineup.stats %>%
        dplyr::group_by(playerId, isOnOrOff) %>%
        dplyr::mutate_at(vars(possessions:minutes), .funs = sum) %>%
        dplyr::mutate_at(vars(fieldGoalsMade:oppDefensiveReboundPct), .funs = sum) %>%
        dplyr::filter(!duplicated(isOnOrOff))

      # If player played every minute for his team, nrow(this.players.onoff.stats) == 1. If so, create needed blank off-row
      if(nrow(this.players.onoff.stats) == 1) {
        off.row <- this.players.onoff.stats %>%
          dplyr::ungroup() %>% dplyr::mutate(isOnOrOff = 'Off Ct') %>%
          dplyr::mutate_at(vars(possessions:oppPersonalFoulsPer40), .funs = function(x) return(0)) %>%

          dplyr::group_by(playerId, isOnOrOff)

        this.players.onoff.stats <- this.players.onoff.stats %>% rbind(off.row)
      }

      # And Rbind to the main container
      on.off.stats <- on.off.stats %>% base::rbind(this.players.onoff.stats)
    }
  }
}
```

Please let me know if there's anything not reproducible about the example. The data fetching, and for-loops, all work on my end. **Code flow** at a high level (this is all in the comments of the code) does this:

1. Filter lineup data for single season
2. Filter lineup data for single team
3. For each player on team, add indicator column `isOnOrOff` that specifies if specified player is one of the 5 players in each lineup/row.
4. Use isOnOrOff column with a group_by to convert the season's-team's lineup stats into on/off stats for the specific player.
5. If player played every single minute for his team, add a blank 'off' row.
6. rbind the player's on/off stats onto the output dataframe.

Following the comments when reviewing the code will hopefully make clear how the code is going about converting the data from lineup stats to on/off stats.

**Current Speed / Future Data:** As far as the current speed, this loop took 1.6 minutes the last time I ran it. With all of the stats (I removed ~300 columns in the example data), the loop takes 3.5 minutes. This is college basketball data, and currently I have only used ~40 teams when building my website. This is going to shortly change to ~350 teams, and with that change, each team will have an additional ~50% more lineups. In total, the size of data will increase by a factor of ~15x.

Given that I'm using a for-loop, I expect at least a 15x slow down, if not more (15x loops but each loop may be slower working with a bigger overall dataset), with the full dataset. I'm also required to call this loop twice each time the code is run, not once. In total, I'm estimating the future run-time at 3.5 * 15x more teams * 2 runs of code == ~105 minutes. This is too long. This code of mine will have to be run daily, and this triple for-loop is only a small part of a much larger script.

**Close:** any help on this is greatly appreciated. I'm aware that this isn't the easiest for-loop to vectorize, and I plan on bountying this post and any super helpful answers if need be.

**EDIT:** A quick shared thought on my approach. I felt that I had to use this nested for-loop approach, because the very important group_by has to be done on the team's lineup stats only. I don't care if a player is off-court if the line-up is for an entirely different team / for a season where the player didn't even play college basketball.

**EDIT 2:** If I could simply run the code inside of the `j` for-loop  for the `i` seasons and `j` teams all simultaneously (for each `i` season, `j` team, identify players on that team, loop players on the team, compute each player's on/off stats, done), that would probably get the job done, right?

Comment: If you eliminate the use of `%>%` inside your loop, it will run faster.

Comment: Looks like you're growing objects within `for-loop` which is highly inefficient and not recommended in `R`. Please see these great posts to find out better ways to do it: [Efficient accumulation in R](http://www.win-vector.com/blog/2015/07/efficient-accumulation-in-r/), 
[Applying a function over rows of a data frame](https://rpubs.com/wch/200398)

Comment: @Tung the entirely of the for-loop only performs ~75 `rbind()` calls - i think in need to remove the whole triple-nested for loop structure, not just remove 75 rbind calls.

Comment: For calculations like `dplyr::mutate_at(vars(possessions:minutes), .funs = sum)`, do you mean `summarise_at` instead?  I would assume you'd want the sum of all the minutes (for example) for that lineup, with and without a player.  But this is adding together all the columns between and including `possessions` and `minutes`, which doesn't seem right.

Comment: @andrew_reece group_by `isOnOrOff` creates 2 groups, 1 group of stats with all lineups with a player on-court, and 1 group of stats with all lineups with a player off-court. For each of these groups, I want to sum every single stat column from possessions to minutes.

`summarise_at` and `mutate_at` would do the same thing here, that being sum each stat over all lineups. with `mutate_at`, i simply don't lose all of the other columns.

Comment: @andrew_reece i think you're right on summarise_at vs mutate_at actually

Comment: @Tung I had no idea how much %>% slows down code compared to traditional base R operations

Comment: You might consider that your post isn't as much in the spirit of SO as it could be.  It's involved and highly task-specific, and you haven't done much work to narrow down your question to a generalized use case that could easily benefit others.  Instead, it's a lot closer to the "free consulting" kind of post that many on this site take issue with.  Meaning, it requires a deep dive into your particular use case and particulars, and a solution will only help others if they spend the same amount of time figuring out where you started from.

Comment: What might have been a good alternative?  You could have constructed a question about how to speed up nested for-loops with a simple dummy example that captured the structure of your problem, but with generalized conditions - this would not only have been more useful for others but I find doing that often helps me refine my own thinking about the problem space I'm dealing with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get significant speedup by leveraging `gather` and `group_by` pivot/aggregate operations.

Starting at `raw.lineup.stats`, here's a pass which should get you most of the way there, at least in rough strokes.  See below for notes.

```
library(tidyverse)

all_seasons <- c('1718', '1819')

# make a list of unique players per team, per season
players <- raw.lineup.stats %>%
  filter(season %in% all_seasons) %>% 
  gather(position, player, starts_with("onCtId")) %>%
  select(season, teamId, player) %>%
  group_by(season, teamId) %>%
  distinct(player, .keep_all = TRUE) %>%
  ungroup()

# cartesian join with the full df
# use lineupId to determine on/off court (on_ct)
# group_by and aggregate, then use distinct to drop duplicate rows
on_off <- inner_join(
    players, raw.lineup.stats, 
    by = c("season" = "season", "teamId" = "teamId")
  ) %>%
  mutate(on_ct = stringr::str_detect(lineupId, player)) %>% 
  group_by(season, teamId, player, on_ct) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(possessions:minutes, fieldGoalsMade:oppDefensiveReboundPct), 
            list(~sum)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  distinct(player, on_ct, .keep_all = TRUE)
```

Here are some test comparisons from running your code vs the updated code:

```
# new code
> on_off[on_off$teamId == "WVU" & on_off$season == "1819", 
+        c("player", "on_ct", "possessions", "minutes")] %>% 
arrange(player) 
                 player on_ct possessions    minutes
1      AndrewGordon4009  TRUE        86.5  46.133333
2      AndrewGordon4009 FALSE       689.0 374.650000
3    BrandonKnappercbd1  TRUE       225.5 123.233333
4    BrandonKnappercbd1 FALSE       550.0 297.550000
5       ChaseHarler8a7e  TRUE       369.5 201.900000
6       ChaseHarler8a7e FALSE       406.0 218.883333
...

# old code
> on.off.stats[on.off.stats$teamId == "WVU" & on.off.stats$season == "1819", 
c("playerId", "isOnOrOff", "possessions", "minutes")] %>% 
arrange(playerId) 
               playerId isOnOrOff possessions    minutes
1      AndrewGordon4009     On Ct        86.5  46.133333
2      AndrewGordon4009    Off Ct       689.0 374.650000
3    BrandonKnappercbd1     On Ct       225.5 123.233333
4    BrandonKnappercbd1    Off Ct       550.0 297.550000
5       ChaseHarler8a7e     On Ct       369.5 201.900000
6       ChaseHarler8a7e    Off Ct       406.0 218.883333
...
```

Notes:

- I'm still using `magrittr` pipes, because I think it's helpful for walking through a problem (and because I think a lot of tidyverse functions are really handy), but you can get some speedup if you want to convert to base R.
- It appears you have a few bugs in your code which are unrelated to this speedup operation you're asking about - this made it much harder to verify against your output, as sometimes your output was wrong.  For example, `JamesBolden043b` plays for team `WVU` in season `1718` only, according to `raw.lineup.stats`, but your `on.off.stats` final output has him playing in season `1819` as well.  I'm also pretty sure your `summarise` vs `mutate` commands aren't giving you exactly what you want.
- If you want player stats for on/off court, per each 5-person on-court configuration, there's an extra layer of grouping, with `lineupId`, that you'll need to do.  (That made more sense to me when I was going through the data, but your call of course.)

I think what's left is syntax adjustments and bug hunting; the main intuition behind this code update should get you most of the way there.  One other adjustment: you'll need to add in the rows which are missing in those cases where a player is on the court 100% of the time - but you don't need a for loop for that either.

Comment: This is amazing andrew, 100% appreciated.

`JamesBolden043b` is certainly in both years however. Run `sum(raw.lineup.stats$onCtId1[raw.lineup.stats$season == "1819"] == "JamesBolden043b")` and you should receive 23 lineups, and 44 for `== 1819`

Comment: I think the only mistake in your code is that the `distinct()` function call at the end needs to include season as well. Otherwise, thank you again !